# Remotely connect to Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

My workplace IT department has a way for us to create virtual machines with an OS of our choice. I just finished creating one with Ubuntu 14.04.

I am assuming Ubuntu 14.04 comes shipped with a VNC server or some sort? How do I run it? I will then connect to it via a VNC viewer on windows.

Secondly, can I configure the VNC server to run the unity desktop instead of gnome? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the `tightvncserver` package to get a VNC server.

When started it will run whatever desktop environment is configured.  I usually look to run a lightweight DE to keep resource usage down (something like icewm).